# 'With' statement with throwaway variables?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Is it possible to do something like the following in python?

```
def func():
    with "Bill" as name:
        print(name)
    # ... more stuff below ...
```

I know it could be done with a function/closure like:

```
def func(): 
    def _with(name):
        print(name)
    _with(name="Bill")
    # ... more stuff below ...
```

But is there another way to do this (without doing a lot of heavy lifting by subclassing the string and doing enter/exit methods?

Comment: Local variables are automatically "thrown away" when the function returns — so you're making things more difficult that necessary IMO.

Comment: No; the function scope is the finest-grain scope available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func():
    name = 'Bill'
    print(name)
```

The variable `name` is thrown away after the function call ends since it is only local to `func`.

NB the colon after the `func` definition.